# passport.deserializeUser() not working with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, passport.js, session-cookies

I'm having trouble searching the user thorough Firebase using the `passport.deserializeUser()` method.

If I write the code like this

```
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
   // id has the correct value, Twitter id for example when user tries to log in
     database.child('people').orderByChild('id').equalTo(id).once('value', user => {
     console.log(user.val()); //null
   });
     done(null, user.val());
});
```

`user.val()` returns `null`.

If I write

```
console.log(user)
```

`user` returns an object even if the value is equal or not.

I know that Firebase has it's own Authentication methods in the web console, but I'm wondering why is this not working? The same method for database `database.child().orderByChild()` works elsewhere but not in `passport.deserializeUser()`.

I've set up the `passport.session`, `cookieParser` and `cookieSession` and the browser does receive the cookie from the server, but when I try to deserialize the user it doesn't work. When I try to authenticate with strategies, it passes through the `passport.deserialize()` but the Firebase part doesn't work, even though it holds the correct `id` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `user` is always going to be a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) object.  The [val()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val) method on that object will return null if there is no data at the location that you queried.  This is all intended behavior of Realtime Database queries, and has nothing to do with authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Didn't knew that.